# How to wrap around right aligned text in a subsection headline?

Tags: floats, sectioning, horizontal-alignment

I want to right align the date in the subsection headlines. The rest of the headline text should flow around that date. I tried using *wrapfig* but it seems to not work within the subsection command.

Example:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\noindent#1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\subsection{%
    \SomehowFloatThisRight{2016-12-11}
    Integer vitae neque vitae eros fringilla rutrum vestibulum in pede adipiscing
    mi dapibus condimentum etiam felis risus
}
```

Output:

```
| Integer vitae neque vitae eros fringilla rutrum     2016-12-11 |
| vestibulum in pede adipiscing mi dapibus condimentum etiam     |
| felis risus                                                    |
```

Comment: Will it be the same date for all subsections?

Comment: @Bernard No, different dates and sometimes date ranges. So the width should be flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant of Piet's answer, with a cleaner interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\typesetdatesubsection}

\newlength{\datespace}
\newcommand{\datesubsection}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\datespace}{\bfseries #1}%
  \def\thissubsectiondate{#1}\subsection*{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\typesetdatesubsection}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\columnwidth][r]{\thissubsectiondate}}%
  \raggedright
  \parshape 2 
    0pt \dimexpr\columnwidth-\datespace-3em\relax
    0pt \columnwidth
  #1%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\datesubsection{2016-12-11}{Integer vitae neque vitae eros fringilla rutrum
  vestibulum in pede adipiscing mi dapibus condimentum etiam felis risus}

\lipsum[3]

\datesubsection{2016-11-11/2016-12-11}{Integer vitae neque vitae eros fringilla rutrum
  vestibulum in pede adipiscing mi dapibus condimentum etiam felis risus}

\end{document}
```

I used `\raggedright` because otherwise the typesetting would be much more problematic.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I must say that I find that a strange way of formatting the subsection title, and it may be confusing for the reader.

That said, you can do this with `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`. However these must be given before the paragraph starts, and you need the size of the "floating" text. So you must specify this **before** the section title, otherwise you are too late. This is better anyway, to make sure this code doesn't go to the Table of Contents, as I am quite sure it would wreak havoc there. I have supposed this code shouldn't go to the TOC. Therefore it is put in the `\titleformat` rather than in the `\subsection`.

Anyway, here is my solution. I put 1cm extra space before the date to clearly separate it from the title.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newlength{\SubsectionFloatLength}
\newcommand{\FloatRightText}{}
\newcommand{\SubsectionFloatRight}[1]{\settowidth{\SubsectionFloatLength}{\hspace{1cm}\bfseries#1}%
       \renewcommand{\FloatRightText}{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\hangindent-\SubsectionFloatLength\hangafter-1\noindent
    \rlap{\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\FloatRightText}}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\SubsectionFloatRight{2016-12-11}
\subsection {Integer vitae neque vitae eros fringilla rutrum vestibulum in pede adipiscing
    mi dapibus condimentum etiam felis risus}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The padding only works in certain cases for me. For example, when I try `2016-12-11 0000000000000000000` as the floating text, it overlaps the subsection header. Maybe it's because we read the text width before applying the formatting. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I failed to take the `\bfseries` into account when measuring the size of the floating text. So change `\newcommand{\SubsectionFloatRight}` to do that. I have done that in my code.

Comment: That looks better now. I needed to appen `\raggedright#1` to the title format in order for the headlines to show up. But there is one more problem: When using this within `\begin{multicols}{2}`, the dates are shifted to the right by the width of one column.

Comment: Change the `\makebox[\textwidth]` to `\makebox[\linewidth]`